# Getting highest number from column using where statement

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get the Highest Value from the column I have around 28000 rows with unique number column referred as Bill Number but in the output, **I am getting the max number 10000 instead of 28000**
I was wondering where have i went wrong ? or any issue in Table?

below are the alternatives I tried

**OPTION NO: 1**

```
    $latest_bill_no_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `central_billing` WHERE `branch_code`='$branch_code' ORDER BY bill_no DESC LIMIT 1" );
    $latest_bill_no_row = mysqli_fetch_array( $latest_bill_no_query );
    $latest_bill_no = $latest_bill_no_row["bill_no"];
```

**OPTION NO: 2**

```
$latest_bill_no_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT MAX(`bill_no`) AS max FROM `central_billing` WHERE `branch_code`='$branch_code'" );
    $latest_bill_no_row = mysqli_fetch_array( $latest_bill_no_query );
    $latest_bill_no = $latest_bill_no_row['max'];
```

SCREENSHOT

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ocz2F.png)

Comment: `ORDER BY bill_no DESC LIMIT 1` should work just fine. I'm guessing that the records with bill_no > 10000 are being excluded by your `where branch_code` clause.

Comment: i just checked everything is under right place its not excluded

Comment: If you run `SELECT bill_no FROM central_billing ORDER BY bill_no DESC LIMIT 1` from the MySQL command line, what do you get?

Comment: I am Getting the Highest Value of 9999

Comment: You've created bill_no as a varchar instead of an int.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` and copy/paste the output to your question

Answer (score 0):

Mysql MIN() and MAX() Functions

The MIN() function returns the smallest value of the selected column.

The MAX() function returns the largest value of the selected column.

MIN() Syntax

```
SELECT MIN(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition;
```

MAX() Syntax

```
SELECT MAX(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition;
```